# How to approach reading a large codebase

Tags: sas

I've moved to a larger organization where there's lots of existing code(mainly SAS - the WPS version).

This is the first time I'm using the language, and I'm having trouble understanding the code, I'm not able to figure out how to approach understanding the large codebase.

P.S : Existing questions were not SAS-specific, I posted so people with SAS experience could help

Comment: Sadly this question is considered too broad for Stack Overflow. Please read the [help] so you can understand the guidelines of the site before posting.

Comment: From the ['what topics can I ask about here'])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), this question is on point #4.

Why would you consider this is 'too broad'?

Comment: What is your new role ? Are you adding features or trouble shooting problems ? Is there any existing documentation ? What is you time allocation for learning ? Does the org have dev/test/prod instances for code development and usage ?  Is there high level of abstraction coded (often evidenced by control tables, macros, and complex parameter sets used to control flow or code generation ). Is the code base mostly ETL, modeling, statistical or reporting ?  Do you have a mentor ? New to the language and a large code base can be similar to being tossed a boulder in the deep part of swift water.

Comment: well said and so true @Richard

Comment: @VarunVembar You never specified that you were looking for an offsite resource. Also, point #4 is still off topic. `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic`. So too broad or off-topic, similar enough in my opinion. Point is this question isn't allowed under the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: Take the free e-course from SAS. Read the documentation, if it doesn't exist, make it as you go through this. However, you're essentially working with a version of 'SAS' that's equivalent to 9.1 or 9.2 so pretty old a lot of the newer more efficient techniques are not available.

Comment: @Richard - The code is mainly for producing reports(raw data is sitting in a Oracle Db). The codebase has a few elements of modeling and statistics to it as well.

I'll be primarily running the code to generate the reports, and then be expected to troubleshoot and contribute too.

This is initial days, so I have time allocated for learning, I'm just feeling a little overwhelmed by the sheer volume, and can't think of an effective strategy to utilize the time.

Comment: @CharlieFish Bullet point #4, which says 'a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development'.

How to read large codebases is something experienced developers can help with. There's nothing specific to SAS on SO.

Comment: Unless you oversold your skills, the best course is to be brutally honest with management, find a technically strong liaison with respect to consumer of end product, and try to run through one report in great detail, perhaps manually submitting functional chunks of code to gain insight into the data model and the earlier teams stratagems. With luck, they were a bit consistent and things learned will be applicable to other data sets and processes within the org

Answer (score 0):

I have converted 1000's of line of code from SAS to Teradata SQL and this are my learnings. if you have basic SAS knowledge, you should be fine. 
It can be complex too, once I had issue with very complex regex code, which was difficult for me at that point of time. following two steps helped me out.

1. Read the code step by step and if you are not clear than run the code step by step in 
   development area, make sure you are not overwriting permanent tables. This will help understand what is happening in each step. Write comments for yourselves at each step, so that you can understand better.
2. If you are assigned for rewrite then run original code(step by step) and rewritten code step by step and compare results (do not overwrite permanent datasets). Also compare final resultant sets too.